# Garbage collection triggered when downloading a large file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, garbage-collection

We need to download multiple large files from S3 and store it on local disk. We see that whenever download happens, GC gets triggered. During GC, the responsiveness of the system is reduced and is increasing the latency of some calls on the system. Below is the code we use to download from cloud. There will be at most 8 threads which download in parallel. Is there anything we can do more efficiently

```
    final GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,
                    key);
    long startIndex = 0L;
    long endIndex = maxBytesToReadPerSecond;
    final long length = metadata.getContentLength();
    final int bufferSize = 1024 * 10;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    try (OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile))) {
        while (startIndex < length) {
            this.rateLimiter.acquire(maxBytesToReadPerSecond);//throttles download
            if (length - startIndex < maxBytesToReadPerSecond) {
                getObjectRequest.setRange(startIndex);
            } else {
                getObjectRequest.setRange(startIndex, endIndex);
            }
            final S3Object s3Object = this.getS3Client().getObject(getObjectRequest);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int bytesReadTotal = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = s3Object.getObjectContent().read(buffer)) > -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesReadTotal += bytesRead;
            }
            startIndex = startIndex + bytesReadTotal;
            endIndex = (endIndex + maxBytesToReadPerSecond > length) ? length : endIndex + maxBytesToReadPerSecond;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never close the input stream of the `S3Object`.

Comment: Closing the stream is said to be important: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#getObjectContent--. However, it may be unrelated to your GC.

Comment: This question requires more detail to be able to provide a reasonable answer. Start with the flags you are using to start your JVM (i.e. how big is the heap?) Also, "multiple large files" is rather ambiguous. How big are they, typically? You should also post details from a GC log file showing what is happening when the collector runs during file loading.